# Spring MVC JavaConfig issue when migrating servletMapping from web.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web.xml, spring-java-config, servlet-mapping

I try to migrate this portion of the web.xml into my Spring MVC 4.0 (Servlet 3.0 no web.xml anylonger ;-) JavaConfig:

Part of the *web.xml*

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>            
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I have no real clue how to do this for my WebAppInitalizer which is the following:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};

    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Many thanks in advance

Cheers

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try This,

The following code is for AppConfig.java,

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.basepackage")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/*");
    }
}
```

And This is for AppInitializer.java,

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(context);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = context.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");

    }

}
```

And the Dependencies Needed ARE,

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi Guna. Thanks for the answer and the code. I overwrite now the `onstartup` method too, but not sure if I did it correctly. You are using `AppConfig.class`. Is ths my `RootConfig.class`? So your `ctx.register(AppConfig.class);` would by `rootContext.register(getRootConfigClasses()[0]);` in my coding? Thanks John.

Comment: Sorry #John , I forgot to add the AppConfig Class at first. Plese try the edited answer.. Thank You..

Comment: Hi Guna. Thanks for that update. It worked. Brilliant. Cheers. John